# syntax error near unexpected token `case'

Tags: bash, shell

This question probably have been asked before but i don't understand what is wrong with this code. so this code is intent to show the menu list of reply variable without any input by user when the user run this code

```
#!/bin/bash
again='y'
while [ $again == 'y' ] || [ $again == 'Y' ];
do
 clear
 select menu in "Food1" "Food2" "Food3";
 case $REPLY in
 1) echo -n "Amount of plate =";
 read sum
 let pay=sum*1500;
 ;;
 2) echo -n "Amount of food =";
 read sum
 let pay=sum*2000;
 ;;
 3) exit 0
 ;;
 *) echo "Sorry, its unavailable"
 ;;
 esac
do
echo "Amount of pay = Rp. $pay"
echo "THX"
echo 
echo -n "Count again (y/t) :";
read again;
 #to validate input
 while [ $again != 'y' ] && [ $again != 'Y' ] && [ $again != 't' ] && [ $again != 'T' ];
 do
 echo "Ops, input with (y/Y/t/Y)";
 echo -n "Count again (y/t) :";
 read again;
 done
done
```

then i get this error

```
./script.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `case'
./script.sh: line 7: ` case $REPLY in'
```

Comment: You forgot the `do` keyword in the `select` statement.

Comment: Or rather, the `case` statement has to come *after* the `do` keyword, not in the list of selections that precedes `do`.

Comment: Also, you are missing a `done` - there should be the same number of `do`s as `done`s (`done` terminates a `do`).

Comment: Normally it is easier to test `$menu` rather than `$REPLY` because if you add items to the menu then you have to change the `case` around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c.f. https://www.shellcheck.net/, which will check your bash syntax for you.

```
Line 6:
 select menu in "Food1" "Food2" "Food3";
 ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this select loop. Fix to allow more checks.

Line 7:
 case $REPLY in
 ^-- SC1058: Expected 'do'.
 ^-- SC1072: Expected 'do'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

shellcheck is your friend. :)

```
select menu in "Food1" "Food2" "Food3"
do : your logic here, AFTER the do
done
```

One more thing to simplify your code - rather than checking the case of everything, just force it for simple things like this.

```
$ declare -l foo
$ foo=BAR
$ echo $foo
bar
```

so if you do this with $again

```
declare -l again=y
while [[ y == "$again" ]]
do : ...
```

you never need to check for Y because it will be y. By the same token, at the bottom -

```
read again
until [[ "$again" =~ [yt] ]]
do printf "Y or T only please. Continue? [Y/t] "
   read again
done
```